# Using mySQL / Anorm getAliased[] causes runtime exception

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, anorm, playframework-2.2

ran into this error. I'am trying to read a aliased column value(ip address), formatted with INET_NTOA. Column is unsigned int.
Following error shows up!

TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert [B@2676c422:class [B to String for column ColumnName(.Alias_ip,Some(Alias_ip)))
java.lang.RuntimeException: TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert [B@2676c422:class [B to String for column ColumnName(.Alias_ip,Some(Alias_ip)))

```
/**
 * The reg parser.
 */
val regDetails = {
  get[Option[Long]]("reg.userId") ~
  getAliased[String]("Alias_ip") map {
  case
      userId ~
      ip => 
      RegDetails(
        userId,
        ip
       )
   }
}


SELECT
  `userId`,
  INET_NTOA(`ip`) AS `Alias_ip`
FROM `reg`
WHERE `userId` = {userID}
```

Did i  forget to convert something?

Any help will be gratefully appreciated.
Oliver

Comment: It looks like INET_NTOA in MySql actually converts to a byte array (this is the `[B` you are seeing) rather than a String. See [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1833-Converting-An-IP-Address-To-An-Integer-Using-MySQL-Thanks-Julian-Halliwell-.htm) for example (and for possible ways around the problem).

Comment: @Shadowlands

Thank you for pointing in the right direction. I just added this converter to my helpers and everything works fine!

implicit def rowToString: Column[String] = Column.nonNull { (value, meta) =>
    value match {
      case byteArray: Array[Byte] => Right(byteArray.mkString)
      case string: String => Right(string)
      case _ => Left(TypeDoesNotMatch("Cannot convert " + value + ":" + value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass))
    }
  }